# How to ignore null value in performing average in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

how can i ignore the value of NULL while performing average function in laravel.
with this code below it is treating the null value as zero.
sorry for my bad english hope you understand what i mean thanks.

**below is my code**

```
$average2 =round( $scores->where('student_id',$id)->avg('term2_result'));
```

Comment: there are some null values in some rows? have you tried not adding them in the computation? add another condition

Comment: yes the row is null able, can give me example on how to set condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$average2 = round($scores->where('student_id', $id)
                        ->where('field_name', '!=', null)
                        ->avg('term2_result'));
```

Comment: Glad to help @Noob